# Get Recovery Code GitHub for 2FA from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, google-2fa

Prev, my device was stolen and I didn't write/save any recovery code for 2FA. Because of that, right now I can't log in to my GitHub account. I already contacted GitHub support but there seems to be no other way to login to GitHub without 2FA.

Also, I just noticed that my GitHub account is still connected with my Android Studio. Is there any way to get recovery code from Android Studio GitHub?

[image]

I also can commit, push, etc from my Android Studio.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials#authenticating-with-a-verified-device-ssh-token-or-personal-access-token

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am very lucky, when I installed the google authenticator again in my new device using same email as github account, the 2FA still there. So right now I can login again to my github account.